# Is there a possibility to prevent files from deleting in specified directory?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, filesystems, hook

I have following situation: I am monitoring a folder with the `FileSystemWatcher` class from .NET (C#). With this class I get to know if a file was deleted but I want the following behaviour: Prevent the file from deleting by cancel deleting and move the file to my own temp directory to give the user the possibility to restore the file.

Is there a possibility to implement such a behaviour? What is the way I have to go? 
Can I hook into some global events? Is it only possibible with an own file system driver?
Or have I to restore the file after getting to know that it was deleted by my own with WinAPI function `CreateFile`?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: why not just use the windows recyclebin? the user can restore it from there (also programmatically from your application if you want that)

Comment: What are the use cases for deleting the file? Is it your application? External (i.e. Explorer) ? i.e. is it is your own app, prevent instead of recover.

Comment: A user can delete a file from explorer, command line and so on. The problem is that a user can hard delete such files. And in this special folder the application should give the possibility to recover deleted files for some time.

Comment: To protect them from doing (some) stupid things, you can turn on volume snapshot service.

Answer (score 4):

The FileSystemWatcher does not provide any mechanisms to intercept file deletes, only report to you what has happened.

How big are the files in question? Depending on the size of these files, one way to achieve (i.e. hack) this is to cache the files elsewhere, out of sight, e.g. in memory or on disk. When your app starts, run through the files and cache them (copy them to a temporary folder or load them into memory). Update the cache when files are changed or created, and provide a way to restore them when they are deleted. It's not pretty, but it would get the job done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but because the filesize is not limited i can not use this solution